# SAML Request (RequestLogout) with IdP-Initiated don't works on Office 365?

Tags: java, office365, saml-2.0, opensaml

I am developing a IdP example and I have had success in the first steps for Logon user, however I have a lot of doubts about RequestLogout with IdP-Initiated flow.

I am following and using the metadata (https://nexus.microsoftonline-p.com/federationmetadata/saml20/federationmetadata.xml).

My RequestLogout looks like this code:

```
<samlp:LogoutRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="my-random-id" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2018-01-22T05:12:01Z" Destination="https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf">
  <saml:Issuer>my-idp-issuer</saml:Issuer>
  <saml:NameID SPNameQualifier="https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">my-name-id-xyz</saml:NameID>
</samlp:LogoutRequest>
```

After I generate this request, I apply the signature of this request (I am following this answer **[Construct a signed SAML2 LogOut request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150096/construct-a-signed-saml2-logout-request)**) :

```
SAMLRequest=saml_request_logout_value&SigAlg=sig_alg_value
```

And I obtain the signature value:

```
Signature=signature_value
```

After I send with a HTTP-POST and redirect to the page: https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf with the values:

```
SAMLRequest=saml_request_logout_value    
SigAlg=sig_alg_value    
Signature=signature_value
```

After sending HTTP-POST the Office 365 presents me with the error message: **An error occurred when we tried to process WS-Federation message. The message was invalid.**

What am I doing wrong?
The parameters sent in HTTP-POST are correct (SAMLRequest, SigAlg, Signature)?
What I believe I may be doing wrong is I don't apply the signature in RequestLogout, because as I am applying the Signature of SAMLResponse and Assertion (in SAMLResponse), I need to apply the Signature of RequestLogout?. However, in the flow SP to IdP, the Office 365 doesn't send RequestLogout with "Signature value" in XML.

I don't see any answer, or any example to send IdP RequestLogout to Office 365.